# In App Purchase - Hosted content version and download iOS

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase, version, iap-hosted-content

I have a question regarding the hosted content package in apple site.
My app version is 1.0 and hosted content version is also 1.0.

If user is downloading app and making in-app purchase then he will get 1.0 version of hosted content package. If suppose after some period(say after 1 week) I am updating hosted content with version 1.1. 
My questions are:
1)Whether old users will able to download new version of hosted content?

a. if YES then how they will be notified by apple and how they will download the data?(process in detail)
b. if NO then what changes I have to make in my code to inform user for the new data?

I have searched a lot but didn't find satisfied answer.
I am little bit confused about the same. If you have any link to refer the same then please suggest.

Comment: Only content, or the App itself ? Is it related to IAP ? but you didn't mention IAP in the question, except in the tags.

Comment: yes, IAP content. I think hosted content is provided in IAP only.

Comment: I have changed the title.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SKProductsRequest response now has a downloadContentVersion you can check to trigger a new download. See full discussion and code at

[Updating content when using Apple-hosted content for In-App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009813/updating-content-when-using-apple-hosted-content-for-in-app-purchase)